# Unable to access my SQLite database since Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 3.0.0

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, nuget

I've recently update the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite NuGet package from 2.2.6 to 3.0.0 in my C# UWP project.

I was able to open my database file without any issue but now VS return me the following exception when I try to open it :

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.'

Just with this code :

```
private readonly SqliteConnection db;

public SqliteHelper(string fileLocation)
{
     fileName = fileLocation;
     backupName = fileLocation.Split('.').First() + ".backup";

     db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=./" + fileLocation);
     db.Open();
}
```

Anyone got the same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks the connection string is not correct. I stored the the db file into uwp `LocalStorage`.  We could use "Filename=sqlite.db" connection string directly within `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`  2.2.6. But, we need combine the full db file path when update to latest version. For the detail please refer the following .

```
public static string  DbFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Sqlite.db");
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=" + DbFilePath)) 
    {
        db.Open();
        String tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";
        SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);
        try
        {
            createTable.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (SqliteException e)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include true in your `SqliteConnection` constructor.

Code:

```
private readonly SqliteConnection db;

public SqliteHelper(string fileLocation)
{
     fileName = fileLocation;
     backupName = fileLocation.Split('.').First() + ".backup";

     db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=./" + fileLocation, true);
     db.Open();
}
```

Comment: Already tried but VS only know :

new SqliteConnection()

new SqliteConnection(string connectionString)

Comment: Have you add `broadFileSystemAccess` capability for your uwp app?